# Cannot connect to created instance in AWS RDS from local machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to the instance that I created in RDS with mysql workbench and I've tried everything I can , but I can't seem to find what is the problem.

Here is my rds instance
[image]
[image]

ec2 security group (outbound/inbound)
[image]
[image]

[image]
I cant find what is wrong with this. Can anyone help me with this ? I've been searching for a solution for two days

Comment: Have you created an inbound rule within the instance for the 3306 Mysql port?

Comment: Yes I created inbound and outbound rule in my firewall settings . btw the instance I created is using port 3309.

Comment: Have you ran the grant all privileges on user@IP to database in your mysql server?

Comment: who's IP should I grant privilege?

Comment: It should be from anyone since your AWS security group settings is taking care of this, however it needs to be granted. It should be something like GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON root@'%' TO * . *  considering root is the user. Take a shot with that and let me know

Comment: How can I grant privilege if I'm not connected to the instance ? I think I am missing something here.

Comment: Are you 100% positive that your external IP address is 118.103.85.86? Could your local firewall be blocking port 3309?

Comment: I've checked with ipchicken.com and amazon suggested the same IP.

Comment: how can I check if 3309 is being blocked by my local firewall ? I mean setting inbound/outbound setting of firewall already takes care of that right?

Comment: Are the 3 subnets that the RDS instance is in public subnets?

Comment: if you mean DB subnet groups , yes.

Comment: yes, they are all there.

Comment: Try this: http://portquiz.net:3309/  if you can connect, it verifies you can make outbound connections on 3309. If it fails, the problem is local.

Comment: Error 10061 (as seen in the screenshot) indicates a network issue, not a user/password issue.

Comment: can't access portquiz.net:3309 but I tried 8080 and It worked. Does that mean 3309 is being blocked by my firewall ?

Comment: If that site fails on 3309, then your PC or firewall is blocking it.

Comment: @MattHouser I'll try to solve the blocked ports and I'll tell you the results.

Comment: @MattHouser tried port 8080 and I can finally connect to my aws instance. Right now I'm still figuring out how to unblock port 3309 which I don't have any idea why it is blocked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my local machine is blocking port 3309 and some other ports. I just changed it to availabe port and It worked.